# How to write to multiple files in the mapper in Hadoop map/reduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, parquet

I have a map reduce job without any reducer that parses input files and write some output on disk in the mappers in Parquet format.
Since this job can take files from several folders as input (one folder per date), I would like to also have the output split into folders, like :

```
01JAN15
    output-0000
    output-0001

02JAN15
    output-0000
    output-0001
```

I looked at the MultipleOutput format class in the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html), but it seems to be working only to write in several folders in the reduce part.

Somehow, writing into multiple files in the same directory works, but i get an exception as soon as i try to write in multiple directories (maybe because some mappers are trying to create the same directory at the same time ?).

FYI my code looks like that in the mapper:

```
mos.write("pb", null, message, date + "/output");
```

and I define the output format like that :

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "pb", ProtoParquetOutputFormat.class,
Void.class, com.google.protobuf.Message.class);
```

The exception I get is:

```
15/01/11 15:05:09 WARN ipc.Client: interrupted waiting to send rpc request to server
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.sendRpcRequest(Client.java:1046)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getBlockLocations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:272)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:180)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Do you know if what i want to do is possible? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks !

Comment: What you are trying to do is very much achievable, and you are exactly doing it in the correct way. The stacktrace that you are getting has nothing to do with MultipleOutputs, something else is creating the problem

Comment: It is weird though that just by removing the "/" in the output filename I get no exception...

Comment: Its really weird. I have tried writing a sample program in my machine it works well with "/", and it is exactly producing the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I know , what you mean but unfortunately (As per my knowledge ) you need to do it by your own

Just create your Driver class extending from Configured and Implementing Tool interface . Then you can simply configure a Callback that will be called after your MapRed execution is completed and then just write the code to move the files in respective folders.

here is the link

[Callback after Mapred complets](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/hadoop-get-a-callback-on-mapreduce-job-completion/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **partitions** to output into different file.

Comment: I'd suggest expanding on how they can use partitions.  Right now while this is the start of an answer, it's more of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**An output file cannot be written by several processes (mappers or reducers)**, therefore in order to generate several output files I either have to define custom partitioning or group the data in the reducer and have the key in the output file name.
It is not possible to have the data from several input files written in the same file by mappers.